# Ajax requests in same or different file

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page where I can add and remove workers.

Should I use one code file for each AJAX request, or can I use one file to handle multiple requests?

I use this code to add a worker:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {addid: id},
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

And this code to remove one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {removid: id},
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

I use this code to handle the requests:

```
if(isset($_POST['removid']){

}

if(isset($_POST['addid']){

}
```

Can I use the same PHP file and URL for these requests, or should I create two files (e.g. `addworker.php` and `removerworker.php`) and put `if(isset($_POST[...])` in each?

Comment: I think better is to create one file with functions like addWorker and removeWorker and other functions related to processing worker data

Comment: That script would form a primitive API. Certainly you can use a single API to process multiple requests.

Comment: you can keep same file and url, but add additional parameter like `mode` that will be description for you what task to do,, `adding`, `removing`, `editing` etc..

Comment: Create one file to handle all your functions. you can use "Switch" case to identify the function called and executed its relevant code.Just pass an extra parameter which specifies the function to call in your ajax request.

Comment: Thanks all! I will stick with same file

Comment: something like this :  $.ajax({
             url: 'process.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {id: id, ftype:'addid'},
             dataType: 'html'

Comment: Typically you would use PUT and DELETE

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','remove-user')` and  `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','add-user')` when setting up the different ajax request.

So in the ajax processing script test with an if statement.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'remove-user') {
  // do stuff to remove user
} else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'add-user') {
  // do stuff to add user
} else {
  // and so on
}
```

Don't know how safe but worked for me.

Comment: This is VERY unsafe, and I would not recommend. You do not want to add and remove users from your database based on an unvalidated request and just a header.